# Laravel - Pass custom data to email view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Following on from a previous question, I have an email controller set up to correctly pass user data to the view. I am now trying to modify it so I can pass some custom data instead. My controller looks like this...

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Welcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $email_data;

    public function __construct($email_data)
    {
        $this->email_data = $email_data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.welcome')->with(['email_data' => $this->email_data]);
    }
}
```

And I am sending the email like this...

```
  /* Create Data Array For Email */
        $email_data = array(
            'first_name'=>'John', 
            'last_name'=>'Doe', 
            'email'=>'john@doe.com',
            'password'=>'temp',
        );

        /* Send Email */
        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Welcome($email_data));
```

Is this correct? When I try using this method it does not seem to be passing the data through to the email template. How can I then access this data within the view?

Comment: You don't need this part `->with(['email_data' => $this->email_data])` if the property is public you can access it in the view

Comment: I have tried without that part, but accessing in the view I get Undefined variable: email. Have tried $email and $email_data->email

Comment: try it like this `$email_data['email']`

Comment: try with         ```return $this->view('emails.welcome', compact('email_data'))```

Comment: @Maraboc - perfect, thats solved it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this part `->with(['email_data' => $this->email_data])` because if the property is public you can access it in the view.

And you are passing an array so you have to access the values like this :

```
$email_data['email'] // ...
```

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried this way ?

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Welcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
       return $this->view('emails.welcome')->with('data', $this->data);
    }
}
```

and then in your controller from where you are creating your array of data,

```
$data = [
    'first_name'=>'John', 
    'last_name'=>'Doe', 
    'email'=>'john@doe.com',
    'password'=>'temp'
];

\Mail::to($user->email)->send(new Welcome($data));
```

Please make sure that you add

```
use Mail;
use App\Mail\Welcome;
```

in your controller.

You can access the data in your view like this

```
{{ $data['first_name'] }}
{{ $data['last_name'] }}
{{ $data['email'] }}
{{ $data['password'] }}
```

**OR**

You can also try [Markdown mails](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#markdown-mailables) for this

Comment: Markdown was the way to go for me

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to pass data through the view. First, any public defenses defined in the mailable class pass automatically through the view.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Welcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.orders');
    }
}
```

In Blade view

```
<div>
    First Name: {{ $firstName }}
    Last Name: {{ $lastName }}
    Email: {{ $email }}
    Password: {{ $password }}
</div>
```

For variables with protected and private properties, it is possible to pass data through a view with the with method

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class Welcome extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $firstName;
    protected $lastName;
    protected $email;
    protected $password;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($firstName, $lastName, $email, $password)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
        $this->lastName = $lastName;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.orders')->with([
            'first_name'=> $this->firstName, 
            ......
        ]);
    }
}
```

In Blade view

```
<div>
    First Name: {{ $firstName }}
    Last Name: {{ $lastName }}
    Email: {{ $email }}
    Password: {{ $password }}
</div>
```